# Installing oDeskTeam in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux

Here's my current situation: I need to install this annoying little app on Arch 64bits, but the [odeskteam](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/odeskteam/) package one from the AUR repositories isn't working.

I've tried the following:

**-- Installing from AUR with Yaourt.** The installation outputs an error:

```
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-alainus/aur-odeskteam/./PKGBUILD: line 40: pkgextract.sh: command not found
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
Aborting...
```

**-- Installing from AUR with Yaourt, and removing line #40 as suggested in comments**:

```
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-alainus/aur-odeskteam/./tmp.sMpeyQoiTy: line 41: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
/tmp/yaourt-tmp-alainus/aur-odeskteam/./tmp.sMpeyQoiTy: line 41: `}'
==> ERROR: Failed to source /tmp/yaourt-tmp-alainus/aur-odeskteam/./tmp.sMpeyQoiTy
Unable to read PKGBUILD
```

-- **Downloading the Arch Linux package from oDesk ([here](http://developers.odesk.com/w/file/53657697/odeskteam-3.2.57-arch-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz)).** The installation complains about qt not being present.

```
 % sudo pacman -U odeskteam-3.2.57-arch-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz                                                                 :(
loading packages...
resolving dependencies...
warning: cannot resolve "qt", a dependency of "odeskteam"
:: The following package cannot be upgraded due to unresolvable dependencies:
      odeskteam

:: Do you want to skip the above package for this upgrade? [y/N] N
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: odeskteam: requires qt
```

After doing sudo `pacman -S qt`, which installs qt5, it still outputs the same.

-- **Installing the windows version through wine.** I cannot paste here the plethora of errors that wine gave me, until I definitely erased everything that had to do with wine for the rest of my life.

-- **Installing it in another computer with Ubuntu 13.04**, and trying to open it through SSH X11 Forwarding. The program opens on the other side, but locally throws an error: oDeskTeam Exited Abnormally.

Can anyone suggest another method for having this installed? I don't want to use a VM just to install a little 900KB app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you really should attempt to build the package by hand, rather than relying on a wrapper like `yaourt`.

If you read the PKGBUILD, you will see that there is a dependency (makedepends) on another AUR package, [pkgextract](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pkgextract/): a shell script that unpacks `.deb` and `.rpm` packages.

Unfortunately, the PKGBUILD for this package just installs the script into the build directory, so you will need to manually move it into your $PATH.

Once you have done that, use `makepkg` to build `odeskteam` and it will work.

Comment: I fixed it by modifying the PKGBUILD file and changed the pkgextract.sh into rpmextract. I posted the correct version with updated md5sums to that package comments. Let me know if there's another way I can contribute. Thanks !

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. For future reference; you should just link to a gist, rather than pasting the PKGBUILD as a comment. Also, you forgot to add `qt` as a depend ;)

Comment: so what's the proper way of installing deb or rpm file in Arch?

Comment: @Alex the "proper" way is to use a PKGBUILD to build it from source.